# Importing Java project to use in a Java Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, dynamic, import, project

Within my Java Dynamic Web Project I'm importing another Java project using Build Path so I can query the classes and use Java reflections. When writing my class I initially tested it by running it as a Java application and it worked. However I am now using the same class as part of a dynamic web project it can't seem to access the imported Java project. I have tried importing it into my project references in Eclipse and it still does not work and outputs the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/q1labs/qa/selenium/widgets/WidgetHandler

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/q1labs/qa/selenium/widgets/WidgetHandler

description The server encountered an internal error (javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/q1labs/qa/selenium/widgets/WidgetHandler) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/q1labs/qa/selenium/widgets/WidgetHandler
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/q1labs/qa/selenium/widgets/WidgetHandler
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
org.apache.jsp.UpdatingDb_jsp._jspService(UpdatingDb_jsp.java:98)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/q1labs/qa/selenium/widgets/WidgetHandler
com.q1labs.qa.xmlgenerator.controller.updatedb.DbUpdateScript.updateObjectTypes(DbUpdateScript.java:40)
com.q1labs.qa.xmlgenerator.controller.updatedb.DbUpdateScript.updateDb(DbUpdateScript.java:31)
org.apache.jsp.UpdatingDb_jsp._jspService(UpdatingDb_jsp.java:88)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your **Project Properties > Deployment Assembly** configuration. Go to **Add** and select **Project** > *Next* and select your project. Now this will only include the classes of your project. If your Java project includes external or other JAR references, you have to also include them manually on your new Web Project by copying them to your `WEB-INF/lib` or by adding them as External Jars. If you do the second one, don't forget to mark them in the *Order & Export* tab.

Comment: I looked in the Deployment Assembly and my Java build path entries weren't added however the project I am importing does not appear in the Java build path entries, probably because it is not a .JAR but an uncompiled project.

Comment: On the **Deployment Assembly** window, when you click on **Add...**, instead of selecting _Java Build Path Entries_, select _Project > Next_ and select it there. This should probably do it. If it works I'll update the answer.

Comment: That seemed to solve the problem only to come up against a new error message:

`HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/NoAlertPresentException`

Comment: Is that setup as a `jar` reference on the java project? If it is, you're just going to have to include it the `WEB-INF/lib` of your web project manually or to reference it as an external JAR (don't forget to check it in the Order & Export settings). It's very dificult to set up the dependencies through standard Eclipse options, I would recomend going Maven on this.

Comment: I have a project that is being used for automation testing which has jar files added. What I want to do is build a front end to the application, I have a script which will check specific classes for what methods they contain which are then saved to a database. I'm not interested the external jar files which get updated frequently, all I want my script to do is load particular classes which are not always known and check their contents.

Comment: But still you neet to include all those core referenced JARs of your Java Project onto your Dynamic web project. The error you mention is telling you that the Selenium jar is not on the classpath. When you include that one, who knows if it will complain about another jar, so better to include all those references again on your new web project

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the war file which is deployed and check if this class file located inside WEB-INF/classes ? If this is the case, check your `source tab` in buildpath